# Display specific data of an app in a different app in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two apps in my Django website, one is called Playlist and it has Song model which in turn has a BooleanField. The other app is called Spotlight and has a Track model. In the Track model, I want to display only the Songs (of the Playlist app) whose BooleanField value equals to True. I know how to do that in the webpage by using filters, but I don't know how to achieve that in the admin panel. How can I do that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField`, you want [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

Comment: So my Model code should look something like :
`from skempi.models import Song,Album

class Track(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song)`

and my admin.py should look like :
`class TrackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    limit_choices_to = {'spotlight': False}`
Is this what you meant?

Comment: If you read the link you'll see that `limit_choices_to` is an argument of the model field constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my original question, and I'm very confused abotu your answers although I read the the link you mentioned. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: `... = models.ForeignKey(..., limit_choices_to=...)`

Comment: Yes, I created a new model in a **different** app and added a "song" field which is a foreignkey as you described.